# How do I fix the TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, split, typeerror, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to split a string into two separate coordinates using `split()`.

The `TypeError` in the headline calls back to these lines:

```py
#Coordinate input
coords = input("Please enter the coordinates of the starting point separated by a space:")

#Turtle moves towards coordinate
turtle.penup()
turtle.forward(float(coords.split[0])*20)
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to read up about it but none of these cases relate to what I'm trying to do as far as I can tell.

Comment: What do you intend by `coords.split[0]`? Did you mean to write `coords.split()[0]`?

Comment: The input is supposed to be a set of two numbers, the first one being the x coordinate of the point. coords.split[0] is supposed to find the first word / number in this case and then make the turtle move along the x-axis towards the point.

I just read the second part of your comment, not sure how I missed it. This is the solution, thank you!

Comment: Also note that `input()` returns a **string**, so after the `split()` you will need to convert each of the two values returned into integers.

Comment: I'm doing that here: `float(coords.split[0])*20`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`coords.split` is a method. You cannot subscript (get an item of) a method. You want to get the first item from the *result* of `coords.split`. To do that, you have to actually *call* the method.

```
turtle.forward(float(coords.split()[0])*20)
```